# Can an outlier record stall all kafka consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We have batch processing in kafka. Assume that you have 10 partition and 10 consumers and a batch size of 100. Let's say each document take 200ms p50; can a record from say, partition 5 which takes upto 5 minutes to process stall other consumers from processing?
We are seeing in production that there is some period of no activity in all consumers when one of the consumer is processing a large document.

Comment: Unclear how your consumers work. You aren't required to wait for records to process

Comment: Also, one partition shouldn't block others